# discord.js v13 temp voice channels - joinVoiceChannel() @discordjs/voice

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to add a command, that allows the creation of temporary voice channels.

I have created a new client within this command to try and get the joinVoiceChannel() params another way.

**File:**

```
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require ('@discordjs/voice')

module.exports = {
  emoji: '',
  name: 'voice',
  description: 'Create a temporary voice channel',
  execute(interaction) {
    console.log('hi')
    joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: interaction.channel.id,
      guildId: interaction.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    })
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\tomfi\Code\DiscordBot\commands\voice.js:11:38)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\tomfi\Code\DiscordBot\events\messageCreate.js:16:17)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\tomfi\Code\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:23:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\tomfi\Code\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\tomfi\Code\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:345:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\tomfi\Code\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:443:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\tomfi\Code\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:300:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\tomfi\Code\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
```

Comment: Which line is this error on? Also, by temporary voice channels, you mean once everyone leaves it's deleted?

Comment: I assume `interaction.member.voice.channel` must be `null`. Whoever uses this command must already be in a voice channel, or this error will occur. One thing you could do is check if it is `null`, and if so, send a message asking the user to join a voice channel.

Comment: @MrMythical sorry! I added some other lines in after submitting this (will edit) error is on:

#11: guildId: interaction.guild.id,

But yes, essentially once the channel is no longer active it will get deleted. Though i'm only concerned about creation at the moment.

Comment: @Cannicide I assumed this might be the case, as other examples seem to only focus on music players, where a bot joins a user. I was hoping to create an empty channel, which could then be joined by others? and/or the bot could move users into it once created?

Comment: @TomFirth well your current code only does the joining part of that functionality. You need to add the channel creation part. See the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create). Then, get the ID of the voice channel you create, and use that as your `channelId`.

Comment: @Cannicide part of my problem is that i've started making this bot with v13. v12 works fine but when I use that functionality, it creates a text channel. @discord/voice has replaced all of that for voice commands now.
I think I read that with v13 if you try to join a channel that doesn't exist, it create a new channel (that's the hope anyway).

Comment: It seems that you are in DM

Comment: @MrMythical I'm in DM? I don't understand.
Well, the custom id is irrelevant, I think i'm currently using the channel.id where the command is called? so that already exists and I would hope it would default into creating a new one. Assuming this isn't the correct method.

Comment: Why would you be trying to join the text channel? The other approach was actually closer

Comment: `joinVoiceChannel` doesn't create a new voice channel if you try to join a nonexistent one. You have to manually create a new voice channel via the main discord.js library, then join it via `joinVoiceChannel`.

Comment: As for "when I use that functionality, it creates a text channel", you can specify what type of channel to create. See the [GuildChannelCreateOptions documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/GuildChannelCreateOptions).

Comment: @Cannicide [v13 voice docs](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html)
"Creating a voice connection is simple" - similar to my code? and then "If you try to call joinVoiceChannel on another channel in the same guild in which there is already an active voice connection, the existing voice connection switches over to the new channel." That was how I understood it.

Comment: Voice *connection* not channel. You will need GuildChannelManager.create for that. I assume you are trying to set the type as `'voice'` but they changed it. Now it's `'GUILD_VOICE'`

Comment: @TomFirth What that is saying is that if your bot is already in a VC in that guild, and then tries to join a different VC, it will switch from the first to the second VC. It does not mention anything about creating a new voice channel.

Comment: "GUILD_VOICE" works. Thank you!

Comment: I made an answer summarizing this discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`joinVoiceChannel` does *not* create a voice channel, it creates a voice *connection*. You need to use [`GuildChannelManager.create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create) instead. Here is how:

```js
const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create("VC_NAME", {
  type: "GUILD_VOICE" //note it is "GUILD_VOICE" and not just "voice" anymore
}
joinVoiceChannel({
  channelId: channel.id,
  guildId: interaction.guild.id,
  adapterCreator: interaction.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
})
```